# Open API 3.0.1 readOnly Annotation

Tags: java, annotations, swagger, openapi

I am having a few problems with the Open API 3.0.1 java annotations to define a property as `readOnly` for a specific method. During a `POST` operation the API expects a `NewAccount` model. Here is a truncated representation of the model;

```
{
    "user": {
        "id": "...",
        ...
    },
    "account": {
        "id": "...",
        ...
    }
}
```

What I need is to define the `user.id` and `account.id` as `readOnly` in this operation. All my docs are generated from code via annotations and this is what I have so far;

```java
    @POST
    @Path("/access/accounts")
    @Consumes("application/json")
    @Operation(
            summary = "Create a new account.",
            description = "Create a new account."
    )
    @Tags({@Tag(name = "account")})
    @RequestBody(
            description = "New accounts required models.",
            required = true,
            content = @Content(
                    schema = @Schema(
                            implementation = NewAccount.class
                    )
            )
    )
    @ApiResponses({
            @ApiResponse(
                    responseCode = "201",
                    description = "The new account.",
                    content = @Content(
                            schema = @Schema(
                                    implementation = Account.class
                            )
                    )
            )
    })
```

Comment: Can you also post the `Account` and `NewAccount` classes? Specifically, how the `id` property is defined and annotated.

Comment: They are not annotated. The annotation is specific to the method so I need to define it in each of the respective methods. However, they are just string values.

Comment: Any word on this. This isn't working for me either in Kotlin using Micronaut

Answer (score 5):

You need to add the `@Schema(accessMode = Schema.AccessMode.READ_ONLY)` annotation to the `id` property. This will mark the `id` property as `readOnly: true` in the generated OpenAPI definition.

Example [from here](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-core/blob/master/modules/swagger-core/src/test/java/io/swagger/v3/core/oas/models/ReadOnlyFields.java):

```
import io.swagger.v3.oas.annotations.media.Schema;

public class ReadOnlyFields {
    @Schema(accessMode = Schema.AccessMode.READ_ONLY)
    public Long id;
}
```

Comment: But that would mark it as permanently `readOnly`. What I am trying to achieve is mark it as `readOnly` just for this specific `POST`. Your annotation is absolutely correct if I wanted it to always be `readOnly`. In my @Schema definition there should be a way to add an `accessMode` for a specific attribute that I can define.

Comment: @tarka I'm having a similar requirement. I want to show the id field only in the request of PUT but not in POST. Have you found any way to do it?